# Automatically deploy new container to Google Cloud Compute Engine from Google Container Registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I have a docker container which I push to GCR like `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/<project-id>/<name>`, and when I deploy it on GCE instance, every time I deploy it creates a new instance and I have to remove the old instance manually. The question is, is there a way to deploy containers and force the GCE instances to fetch new containers? I need exactly GCE, not Google Cloud Run or other because it is not an HTTP service.

I deploy the container from Google Console using the `Deploy to Cloud Run` button
[image: Deploy]

Comment: Deployments are supposed to be atomic. It is not considered a good practice to update the current VM to use the new image. Rather, you should use a managed instance group to replace the old VMs with new VMs by updating the instance template.

Comment: You must create a new VM and delete the other. You can write a Cloudbuild.yaml file that do that for you at each CI/CD pipeline run

Comment: You will need to write a small application on GCE that subscribes to Pub/Sub notifications created by Cloud Build. You can then either pull the new container or launch a new instance. Your question is not clear what you want to do. https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/subscribe-build-notifications

Comment: @JohnHanley, I am trying to do something like a CI\CD deployment. In Gitlab I am used to tell my server over ssh to build a new image and start running it. Here I want something similar, push new image, and make the instance build it, and run. In our case the image is already built, so we only need to run it, but it runs in a new instance...

Comment: @JohnHanley, so what I want is to make the instance to pull the image, stop the already running one and start the new one

Comment: You can create a Cloud Build step that uses **gcloud compute ssh --tunnel-through-iap** to connect to the Compute Engine instance and then run commands.  You will need to grant the cloudbuild service account the necessary roles (roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1, roles/compute.viewer, roles/iam.serviceAccountUser, roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor). This will work for pulling a new container. I am not sure about creating a new VM instance from Cloud Build, configuring the instance and pulling a new container. I am not sure why you want to pull a new container and then create a new instance.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I do not want to create a new instance of VM, that is the problem I am trying to solve. Imagine you have servers with your backend running on, and you deploy new features every day, like twice a day. I need existing servers to stop the old version and run the new version of the backend with the new features, without recreating any servers

Comment: Then my last comment should solve your problem.

Comment: @Mattern did you try solution provided by John Hanley? Did you try it?

Comment: @PjoterS, not yet, but I guess it will work. By the way, while I was poking around I found out there is a way to do the exact thing I want with cloud run, there is an option to set up a CI\CD

Comment: I've read your question once again. You want to deploy a container from GCR on GCE, but in the UI you are creating it using the `Deploy to Cloud Run` button. Could you share your scenario? In [Using Container Registry with Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-with-google-cloud-platform) you have which GCP products supports GCR. `Cloud Run` and `Google Kubernetes Engine` are also using `Compute Engine` which provides VMs for both products. `Cloud Run` is a fully managed serverless platform where you don't need to install any libraries, packages, etc.

Comment: You would like to run a few containers with different apps in the one GCE VM or you want to update your image with new features and run it again on the same VM?

Comment: @PjoterS, exactly. I want to update the image with new features and run it again on the same VM

Comment: You would improve only one image of an application or multiple? If you would just want one, you could think about [AppEngine with cloud build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-appengine). It's also possible to use Artifact Registry with App Engine like [here](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/integrate-app-engine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this `Community Wiki` for better visibility. In the comment section there were already a few good solutions, however at the end OP wants to use `Cloud Run`.

At first I'd like to clarify a few things.

> I have a docker container which I push to GCR like `gcloud builds submit`

`gcloud builds submit` is a command to build using Google [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs).

> Cloud Build is a service that executes your builds on Google Cloud Platform infrastructure. Cloud Build can import source code from Cloud Storage, Cloud Source Repositories, GitHub, or Bitbucket, execute a build to your specifications, and produce artifacts such as Docker containers or Java archives.

In this question, OP is referring to [Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/overview), however GCP recommends to use [Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry) which soon will replace `Container Registry`.

Pushing and pulling images from `Artifact Registry` is explained in [Pushing and pulling images](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling) documentation. It can be done by `docker push` or `docker pull` command, where earlier you have to tag an image and create `Artifact Registry`.

**Deploying on different GCP products**

Regarding deploying on `GCE`, `GKE` and `Cloud Run`, those are GCP products which are quite different from each.

[GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute) is `IaaS` where you are specifying the amount of resources and you are maintaining all the installation of all software (you would need to install Docker, Kubernetes, programming libs, etc).

[GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) is like `Hybrid` as you mention the amount of resources you need but it's customized to run containers on it. After creation you already have docker, kubernetes and other software needed to run containers on it.

[Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) is a serverless GCP product, where you don't need to calculate the amount of needed resources, installing software/libs, it's a fully managed serverless platform.

When you want to deploy a container app from `Artifact Registry / Container Registry`, you are creating another VM (GCE and GKE) or new service (Cloud Run).

If you would like to deploy new app on the same VM:

- On GCE, you would need to pull an image and deploy it on that VM using Docker or Kubernetes (Kubeadm).
- On GKE you would need to deploy a new `deployment` using command like

```
kubectl create deployment test --image=<location>-docker.pkg.dev/<projectname>/<artifactRegistryName>/<imageName>
```

and delete the old one.

In `Cloud Run` you can deploy an app without concerns about resources or hardware, which steps are described [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying). You can create `revisions` for specific changes in the image. However `Cloud Run` also allows CI/CD using `GitHub`, `BitBucket` or `Cloud Source Repositories`. This process is also well described in GCP documentation - [Continuous deployment](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build)

**Possible solutions:**

- Write a Cloudbuild.yaml file that do that for you at each CI/CD pipeline run
- Write a small application on GCE that subscribes to Pub/Sub notifications created by Cloud Build. You can then either pull the new container or launch a new instance.
- Use `Cloud Run` with `CI/CD`.

Based on one of the OP's comments, as chosen solution was to use `Cloud Run` with `CI/CD`.